# How do I suppress unnecessary output from RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rvm

I have RoR 4.1.4 running along with RVM. RSpec version is 2.14.8. Also, Capybara is v2.1.0. Every time I run `rspec` I get a keister-load of unnecessary output:

```
# /home/msnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
# /home/msnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
# /home/msnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
# /home/msnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
# /home/msnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
# /home/msnyder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
</snip>
```

Is there a way to suppress this output so I only see the interesting stuff?

EDIT: I've updated RSpec to 3.2.1 and Capybara to 2.4.4. The full backtrace persists even though I have not set `--backtrace` in either the command that I'm running nor the `.rspec` file.

Answer (score 1):

I put this in my rails_helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Cleaner backtrace for failure messages
  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns = [
    /\/lib\d*\/ruby\//,
    /bin\//,
    /gems/,
    /spec\/spec_helper\.rb/,
    /lib\/rspec\/(core|expectations|matchers|mocks)/
  ]
end
```

You can also read up on the docs here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/excluding-lines-from-the-backtrace

Comment: Tried that. It told me that the backtrace_exclusion_patterns method does not exist.